# how to understand f[{1,2,3,4}]?

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

As far as my understanding of function in Mathematica, its core is pattern match, but why `f[{a,b,c}]` (when f is defined) can work correctly? in my understanding, `f[{1,2,3,4}]` correspond to `f[{x_,y_,z_,w_}]:=`

btw, a related question is what is difference of `/@` and `@`?

[image]

Comment: You should look up the `Listable` attribute in the documentation. You might also find this question and string of answers useful: [18393](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: On top of what @N.J.Evans suggested, maybe you can have a look at what [the @#%^&*?! do](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)

Comment: `x_` gets matched to the entire list. Remove the braces, if these are supposed to be four arguments. The provided list is squared. See `Attributes[Power]`. The `Listable` attributes applies the square to each element of the list. Similarlt `Plus` adds `1` to each element of the `List`.

Comment: I think discussing `Listable` is not yet necessary at this stage of understanding. The direct answer to the question is that `_` matches _any_ expression (including a list), not just numbers, as you seem to assume. `x_` is just a named version of `_`. Note that arithmetic works on lists, e.g. `{1,2,3}^2` evaluates to `{1,4,9}`. Recommended readings: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html

Comment: @Syed, thanks. but if i just define a function f[{x_,y_,z_,w_}]:=x+y+z+w , now f[{1,2,3,4}] matches two patterns f[x_] and f[{x_,y_,z_,w_}], which one will be chosen?  in my test answer is f[{x_,y_,z_,w_}], but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on the comments:

```
ns = {1, 2, 3, 4}
ns^2  (* all the squares *)
Attributes[Power] (* this is why (it's Listable) *)
```

And this is why your function definition matches the list with the blank:

```
MatchQ[ns, _]   (* True because a Blank matches any expression *)
```

Comment: thanks. but if i just define a function f[{x_,y_,z_,w_}]:=x+y+z+w , now f[{1,2,3,4}] matches two patterns f[x_] and f[{x_,y_,z_,w_}], which one will be chosen?  in my test the answer is f[{x_,y_,z_,w_}], but why?

Comment: @Aerterliusi I think you are asking what happens if you give `f` *both* definitions. This is quite a different question so you should ask it separately. But briefly, both definitions will be in the `DownValues` of `f`, but the most specific definition will be applied. See the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html).